# Return an arbitrary object when referencing an instance of a class in Python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, magic-methods

For the purpose of quickly operating on json objects in a Dash application, I am using dcc.Store to pass a dictionary (you cannot pass objects in dcc.Store) between callbacks. However I want to construct a dictionary out of class instance (Preferably from a dataclass) and then return it to the data property of the aforementioned component. My problem could be summed up as the following questions:

Can you return a value of an arbitrary type (in this example I want to return a dictionary) when calling on an instance? e.g. this snippet:

```
@app.callback(Output("my-store", "data"),

################
 some code here
################

my_instance = MyDataClass(field1, field2, field3)

return my_instance
```

would have the same functionality as this snippet:

```
@app.callback(Output("my-store", "data"),

################
 some code here
################

my_instance = MyDataClass(field1, field2, field3)

return my_instance.my_dictionary
```

I am aware of `__repr__` and `__str__`, however they must return a **string** representation of the object. I am also aware of `__call__`, but that requires parenthesis when invoking the instance name. Is is possible to cast the instance of a class to a certain type when assigning it?

Comment: I don't see why an explicit attribute lookup is something is worth avoiding. No, a function cannot implicitly operate on the value returned by a `return` statement.

Comment: You would have to specify *somewhere* that it's the `my_dictionary` attribute from `my_instance` that should really be returned; might as well do it in the `return` statement.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to save a reference to the object, though; `return MyDataClass(field1, field2, field3).my_dictionary` would work just as well.

Comment: @chepner Of course I am not saying it is something worth avoiding, I was just curious if it is possible in Python. I already solved this "problem" as it is not really a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in your class so that it behaves like a dictionary:

```
class MyDataClass:
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.my_dictionary[item]

    def __setitem__(self, item, value):
        self.my_dictionary[item] = value
```

Comment: This would be the same as manually returning fields of the class, if I implement something like `def __getitem__(self, _):
        return self.my_dictionary` I still have to use `return my_instance[_]`, which is not exactly what I was asking about. I was asking if you can abstract away the type of object you get when calling an instance or assigning to it.

Comment: If you are returning the instance to something that will use it like a dictionary, then you can just do `return my_instance` and when the code that gets it tries to access it like a dictionary using `[]`, that will trigger the `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` functions. I'm not entirely clear what you're trying to do, though.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to somehow change what is returned when an object is being assigned to another object, so the class would behave like a dictionary. Maybe by using a dataclass or some other decorator. I already solved the problem I was initially faced with it.